# match check in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, match

i have strings like these:

```
s{1,2} = 'string';
s{2,2} = 'string2';
```

and in workspace structure like this

```
U.W.string = [2 2.5 3]
```

I want to check (in loop) s{1,2} or s{2,2} or s{i,2} matches any structure with the same name. If so, assign values from this structure to some variable var(i). How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isfields` to check, if a string is the name of a field in a struct. Then use the syntax `struct.(name)`, where `name` is a string to access the field. Your code might look something like:

```
test = struct('hello', 'world', 'count', 42, 'mean', 10);

fields = {'test', 'count';
          'hello', 'text';
          'more', 'less'};
values = {pi, 'dummy', -1};

for row = 1 : size(fields, 1)
    for column = 1 : size(fields, 2)
        if isfield(test, fields{row, column})
            test.(fields{row, column}) = values{row};
        end
    end
end
```

This converts the initial struct

```
test =
    hello: 'world'
    count: 42
    mean: 10
```

to this one

```
test =
    hello: 'dummy'
    count: 3.1416
    mean: 10
```

A shorter implementation is achieved by removing the inner loop and giving a cell-array to `isfields`:

```
for row = 1 : size(fields, 1)
    %# Note the parenthesis instead of curly braces in the next statement.
    match = isfield(test, fields(row, :));
    if any(match)
        test.(fields{row, match}) = values{row};
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isfield(structName,fieldName). This should do the trick:

```
strings{1,1} = 'foo';
strings{1,2} = 'bar';
strings{1, 3} = 'foobar';

U.W.foo = 1;
U.W.foobar = 5;

for idx = 1:length(strings)
    if(isfield(U.W,strings{1,idx}))
        expression = sprintf('outvar(idx) = U.W.%s',strings{1,idx});
        eval(expression);
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw @Mehrwolf posted just before me.